# Best way to divide the string from specific character | PHP

Tags: php, laravel, split, substr

> Sorry! This question may be similar but not a duplicate ...

Suppose I have strings of different sizes as follows:

```
zinc tab. 25mg №60
vita sip bla b6 50% b6mg №7
5-nok tab. 50mg №50
Blah blah №50
```

In short, I need the result should be as follows:

```
$str1 = "zinc tab"; $str2 = "25mg №60";
$str1 = "vita sip bla b6"; $str2 = "50% b6mg №7";
$str1 = "5-nok tab."; $str2 = "50mg №50";
$str1 = "Blah blah"; $str2 = "№50";
```

The allocated value starts with a number. That is, the number starting from the last part need to be divided into two.
I tried with `implode()`, `explode()`, `preg_split()`, `preg_match()` functions. But they are broken down into several parts with a certain precision. For example:

```
$str = 'Bla bla 50% 400mg №4';
$results = preg_split('/[^0-9]/', $str);
print_r($results);
// Also i got same result with explode, implode functions...

//Then also tried with substr functions like that
$str[strlen($string) -2];

//But string indices are not always the same.
```

I’ve also worked with `substr()` functions, but the string index not always the same. Sometimes it can come in third or second place from the last.
I need the result as follows: If any word at the end of the text begins with a number or begins with №, it should be divided into two at this point. Like that:

```
4 bla bla 40% 50mg №50 should return: 1) 4 bla bla 2) 40% 50mg №50
4 bla bla №50 should resturn 1) 4 bla bla, 2) №50
```

How is it easy and fast to get such a result?
Thanks!

Comment: explode() ? Some times easy way.

Comment: No explode separates them all into an array. I just need to split it in two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nowhere what I would call a robust regex.
But it clears the test.

It tries to find the delimiting "words" and which seems to be number-letter or №-number or number-percent

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?)\s([\d|№]+[a-zA-Z%0-9]{1}.*)/", $str, $m);
```

https://3v4l.org/cSXec